# Leaflet GeoJSON display certain polygon areas based on position(longitude & latitude) of the area

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'm creating a Choropleth Map using Leaflet. The dataset used for creating polygon on the map is in Geojson form. It includes data(latitude and longitude) regarding the positions of the areas. What should I do to only show the tiles I want(the ones insides the red border) on the map?

[image: I want to only show the tiles insides the red border]

Comment: See the `bounds` option of `L.TileLayer`. https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#tilelayer

Comment: Do you mean you want to _filter_ your GeoJSON Features before displaying them?

Comment: Yes. I just want to show the tiles inside the red border